# Selectable custom ListView

Tags: java, android, listview

I have found several questions like these, and I do get that I should be using the `setOnItemClickListener` as:

```
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(position) {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            String Value = listView.getItemAtPosition();
        }
    });
```

However, I am not able to get this working. Its a bit tricky since I am generating the listView dynamically from a JSON Array.

I am using Intent to pass the data as a string to `DisplayListView` class:

```
public class DisplayListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String response;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    DrinksAdapter drinksAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_listview_layout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        drinksAdapter = new DrinksAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(drinksAdapter);
        response = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray  = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("Menu");
            //jsonArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Menu");
            int count = 0;
            String ime,kolicina,cijena;


            while(count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                ime = JO.getString("ime");
                kolicina = JO.getString("kolicina");
                cijena = JO.getString("cijena");

                Drinks drinks = new Drinks(ime,kolicina,cijena);
                drinksAdapter.add(drinks);

                count++;

            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

In the above, Im looping through the array and initializing data by calling `DrinksAdapter`:

```
public class DrinksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
    List list = new ArrayList();

    public DrinksAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
        super(context, resource);
    }


    public void add(Drinks object) {
        super.add(object);
        list.add(object);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return list.size();
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return list.get(position);
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

        View row;
        row = convertView;
        DrinkHolder drinkHolder;

        if(row == null) {
            LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
            drinkHolder = new DrinkHolder();
            drinkHolder.tx_ime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_ime);
            drinkHolder.tx_kolicina = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_kolicina);
            drinkHolder.tx_cijena = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_cijena);

            row.setTag(drinkHolder);
        } else {
            drinkHolder = (DrinkHolder) row.getTag();
        }


        Drinks drinks = (Drinks) this.getItem(position);
        drinkHolder.tx_ime.setText(drinks.getIme());
        drinkHolder.tx_kolicina.setText(drinks.getKolicina());
        drinkHolder.tx_cijena.setText(drinks.getCijena());
        return row;

    }

    static class DrinkHolder {
        TextView tx_ime,tx_kolicina,tx_cijena;
    }

}
```

`Drinks` class is being used to initialize the variables.

Where can I implement this function?

I know I have a lot to learn and I am doing so every day, it looks like Im just a bit stuck at the moment :(

Any kind of help is highly appreciated.
Thank you!

Comment: you want a certain item in the list to be clicked or whole fragment or whole list?

Comment: the idea is to select the row in the list view, from which I am able to figure out those three elements that are set there as TextViews

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can activate a listener on certain elements in the view in `getView` method by

```
drinkHolder.tx_cijena .setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) { 
         //using value of `int position` in `getView` to know which item in the list is clicked
   }
```

Like this

```
public class DrinksAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {
List list = new ArrayList();

public DrinksAdapter(@NonNull Context context, @LayoutRes int resource) {
    super(context, resource);
}


public void add(Drinks object) {
    super.add(object);
    list.add(object);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return list.size();
}

@Nullable
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {

    return list.get(position);
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {

    View row;
    row = convertView;
    DrinkHolder drinkHolder;

    if(row == null) {
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        row = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.row_layout,parent,false);
        drinkHolder = new DrinkHolder();
        drinkHolder.tx_ime = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_ime);
        drinkHolder.tx_kolicina = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_kolicina);
        drinkHolder.tx_cijena = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.tx_cijena);

        row.setTag(drinkHolder);
    } else {
        drinkHolder = (DrinkHolder) row.getTag();
    }


    final Drinks drinks = (Drinks) this.getItem(position); //make it final
    drinkHolder.tx_ime.setText(drinks.getIme());
    drinkHolder.tx_kolicina.setText(drinks.getKolicina());
    drinkHolder.tx_cijena.setText(drinks.getCijena());
     drinkHolder.tx_ime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
     //do anything with your **drink** object get any present value
    Log.i("INFO", drinks.getIme()); // you will log whichever text is clicked in Ime of each list item
     }
    }
    return row;

}

static class DrinkHolder {
    TextView tx_ime,tx_kolicina,tx_cijena;
}

}
```

Comment: thank you so much for you effort. It works just fine. 
Got 2 more questions if you dont mind.  
Is it possible to select the entire row of a listview and get the values of all items within it (in this case, tx_ime,cijena,kolicina)?   
Second question is, how would I go about converting the selectable item to a string. This fails for a reason, but I just dont understand it enough: https://pastebin.com/J64gn1e5 
Thanks again for your effort!

Comment: like suppose you can give `RelativeLayout` an id and you cant get all child elements through this id so you know which layout is clicked

Comment: you can convert it to a string by using you Drink class object see i have updated the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to just plop that listener into the onCreate method, attaching it to the ListView. Try something like this and let us know the results:

```
public class DisplayListView extends AppCompatActivity {
    String response;
    JSONObject jsonObject;
    JSONArray jsonArray;
    DrinksAdapter drinksAdapter;
    ListView listView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.display_listview_layout);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);
        drinksAdapter = new DrinksAdapter(this,R.layout.row_layout);
        listView.setAdapter(drinksAdapter);
        response = getIntent().getExtras().getString("json_data");

        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
            jsonArray  = new JSONObject(response).getJSONArray("Menu");
            //jsonArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("Menu");
            int count = 0;
            String ime,kolicina,cijena;


            while(count < jsonArray.length()) {
                JSONObject JO = jsonArray.getJSONObject(count);
                ime = JO.getString("ime");
                kolicina = JO.getString("kolicina");
                cijena = JO.getString("cijena");

                Drinks drinks = new Drinks(ime,kolicina,cijena);
                drinksAdapter.add(drinks);

                count++;

            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(position) {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
                Drink drink = adapterView.getItem(i);
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: Hey amacf, thank you for your answer. The issue that I was facing to begin with (one of them) was: Cant resolve symbol 'position', as well as Drink. :(